# Proving $\cosh\alpha = \frac{\cos a}{1-\cos a}$ for a regular hyperbolic triangle with all side-lengths $\alpha$ and all angles $a$

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

> Consider a regular triangle in the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$ (i.e. a triangle with all sides length $\alpha$ and all angles $a$).
>
> Prove that $\cosh\alpha = \frac{\cos a}{1-\cos a}$.

I think I have to use the hyperbolic law of cosines:
$$\cosh\alpha = \cosh\beta \cosh\gamma - \sinh\beta\sinh\gamma\cos a$$
simplifies to
$$\cosh\alpha=\cosh^2\alpha - \sinh^2\alpha\cos a$$ in this case, but I don't see how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cosh\alpha = \cosh\beta \cosh\gamma - \sinh\beta\sinh\gamma\cos \alpha$$

Let

$$ \cos(\text{any of the 3 vertex angles} )=c, \cosh\alpha =ch,~\sinh\alpha =sh,~ch^2-sh^2==1 ~$$

$$ ch = ch^2- (ch^2-1) ~c \tag 1 $$

As @Blue mentions this is factorized:

$$ ch^2 (1-c) -ch + c=0 ~ \to ( ch-1)( ch-\frac{c}{1-c})=0;~ \cosh(\alpha)=(1,\frac{c}{1-c}) \tag 2 $$

*Poincaré disc model.*

The *first* solution has non-zero $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\pi/3$ blunt equilateral triangle inside the boundary. Hyperbolic length of each side is finite

The *second* solution has hyperbolic equilateral triangle spikes touch each other $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)= 0 $ and are perpendicular to the boundary / horizon.  Hyperbolic lengths from vertex to vertex ( on the boundary ) are infinite.

[image]

Comment: The quadratic formula is a bit of overkill. The equation factors nicely. :)

Comment: Yes, dear @Blue, I was thinking more of the triangle visualization ( that was  not asked for ! ).

Comment: The angle is zero and the lengths are infinite in the second example.

Comment: Thanks, I shall mention it in an edit